# Clang replacement for -mthreads option

Tags: c++, multithreading, llvm-clang

When I compile a project with clang using `-mthreads` option I have a warning: `argument unused during compilation '-mthreads'`. Is there correct replacement for `-mthreads` in clang. Or what must I do to compile a project correct in this case.

Comment: Don't you mean just plain `-pthread`? Don't Clang use it for compatibility with GCC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `-pthread` flag, and not `-mthreads`.

PS: GCC uses that flag too.